# how to create dynamic row with input fields in html table from given row

Tags: javascript, html

Im new for Html and javascript. I want to create dynamic row with input fields in table while click button,that number of row given from user. In my code, row created dynamically but its not append prevoius one. Its created freshly. But ,I want to append row if table already created.

Here my code:

```js
function createTable() {
  var a;

  a = document.getElementById('tb1').value;

  if (a == "") {
    alert("Please enter some numeric value");
  } else {
    var rows = "<th>Item Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>QuantityType</th><th>Amount</th>";
    for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
      rows += "<tr><td><input type='text' name='" + "name".concat(i+1) + "'></td><td><input type='text' name='" + "quantity".concat(i+1) + "'></td><td><input type='text' name='" + "qtype".concat(i+1) + "'></td><td id='amt'><input type='text' id='sum' onkeyup='myfunction(this.value);' name='" + "total".concat(i+1) + "'></td></tr>";
    }

    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = rows;
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="tb1"/>
    <button type="button" onclick='createTable()'>Click Me!</button>
    <table id="table" class="order-table table"  name="table1" required>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please anyone help!

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `Element.appendChild` instead of `innerHTML`

- `Element.firstChild` will return `first-child` of the element.
- `querySelectorAll` will return `NodeList` as per the specified selector.
- `Element.appendChild` will append new `Node` in the Element without affecting existing content in the Element.

```js
function createTable() {
  var a = document.getElementById('tb1').value;
  if (a == "") {
    alert("Please enter some numeric value");
  } else {
    var th = document.querySelectorAll('#table th');//To check whether `TD` is appended in table or not!
    if (!th.length) {
      //If not appended, then append TD in table
      var rows = "<th>Item Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>QuantityType</th><th>Amount</th>";
      var table = document.createElement('table');
      table.innerHTML = rows;
      document.getElementById("table").appendChild(table.firstChild);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
      var elems = '';
      elems += "<tr><td><input type='text' name='" + "name".concat(i + 1) + "'></td><td><input type='text' name='" + "quantity".concat(i + 1) + "'></td><td><input type='text' name='" + "qtype".concat(i + 1) + "'></td><td id='amt'><input type='text' id='sum' onkeyup='myfunction(this.value);' name='" + "total".concat(i + 1) + "'></td></tr>";
      var table = document.createElement('table');
      table.innerHTML = elems;
      document.getElementById("table").appendChild(table.firstChild);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
table {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tb1" />
<button type="button" onclick='createTable()'>Click Me!</button>
<table id="table" class="order-table table" name="table1" required>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I have one more doubt can you help me

Comment: In that last cell each row, i want to sum what are all numbers i gave. i want only in onkeyup method. If i delete i want to subtract.. How to do

Comment: @hikoo — That could be another question! Nice little research will solve this question I reckon...

Answer (score 0):

First of all You are missing `<tr></tr>` in wrapping the `th`, wrap the `th` in `tr`, and for new `rows` to append the `previous row` you have to use the `insertRow` porperty of javascript.

**Here is your modified snippet**

Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        div {
            background: red;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        table {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }

        td {
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid lightgrey;
        }

    </style>

    <script>

        function createTable() {
            var a;

            a = document.getElementById('tb1').value;
var length = document.getElementById('table').rows.length;
            if (a == "") {
                alert("Please enter some numeric value");
            } else {
              if(length > 1){
                
                var table = document.getElementById("table");
// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
var row = table.insertRow(length);

// Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='" + "name".concat(length+1) + "'>";
                 cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='" + "name".concat(length+1) + "'>";
                 cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='" + "name".concat(length+1) + "'>";
                 cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='" + "name".concat(length+1) + "'>";
              } else {
                var rows = "<tr><th>Item Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>QuantityType</th><th>Amount</th></tr>";
                for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                    rows += "<tr><td><input type='text' name='" + "name".concat(i+1) + "'></td><td><input type='text' name='" + "quantity".concat(i+1) + "'></td><td><input type='text' name='" + "qtype".concat(i+1) + "'></td><td id='amt'><input type='text' id='sum' onkeyup='myfunction(this.value);' name='" + "total".concat(i+1) + "'></td></tr>";
                }

                document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = rows;
                }

            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="tb1"/>
<button type="button" onclick='createTable()'>Click Me!</button>
<table id="table" class="order-table table"  name="table1" required>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did was setting new value to the table each time. what you actually would like to do is appending data to the table using "appendChild" function. this can also be created, even more easily, using

here is a working fiddle with the change (using js appendChild):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        div {
            background: red;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        table {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }

        td {
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid lightgrey;
        }

    </style>

    <script>

        function createTable() {
            var a;

            a = document.getElementById('tb1').value;

            if (a == "") {
                alert("Please enter some numeric value");
            } else {
                var rows = "<th>Item Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>QuantityType</th><th>Amount</th>";
                for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                let tr = document.createElement("tr");
                tr.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text' name='" + "name".concat(i+1) + "'></td><td><input type='text' name='" + "quantity".concat(i+1) + "'></td><td><input type='text' name='" + "qtype".concat(i+1) + "'></td><td id='amt'><input type='text' id='sum' onkeyup='myfunction(this.value);' name='" + "total".concat(i+1) + "'></td>";
                document.getElementById("table").appendChild(tr);
                }                
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="tb1"/>
<button type="button" onclick='createTable()'>Click Me!</button>
<table id="table" class="order-table table"  name="table1" required>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

i would recommend learning to use jquery. anyway, here is some info about the functions i mentioned:
jquery and their "append" function.

info about js appendChild - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp
jquery append - http://api.jquery.com/append/